# How to loop through a JSON object with typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I use angular 7.
my query return a json data which has this format :

```
[
    {
        "text": "test 1",
        "value": "1",
        "nbr": "1",
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "test 1_1",
                "value": "1_1",
                "nbr": "2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "text": "test 1_1_1",
                        "value": "1_1_1",
                        "nbr": "1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "test 1_1_2"",
                        "value": "1_1_2",
                        "nbr": "0",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "test 1_1_3"",
                        "value": "1_1_3",
                        "nbr": "0",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "test 1_2",
                "value": "1_2",
                "nbr": "0",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "test 2",
        "value": "2",
        "nbr": "0",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

I want to loop this data and essentially loop the children data.

and I want to make some test.

I try with this code which has problem to loop children data.

```
      this.httpservice.query({

      }).subscribe((res: HttpResponse<TestEntity[]>) => {
        this.temp= res.body;

        this.temp.forEach((x) => {


            x["children"].forEach(x => {
                if(x.nbr=='0')
                {
                  //  test code
                }
                x["children"].forEach(x => {
                    if(x.nbr=='0')
                    {
                        //  test code
                    }

                    })
                })



            });


      });
```

I didn't find the way to loop the children data .

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
const objects = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]);
```