# How to loop through json defined in typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm working with Angular. There is a similar question but not answered -

[How to loop through a JSON object with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108946/how-to-loop-through-a-json-object-with-typescript)

I'm not getting any error or warning. But I'm not getting the output also. I'm trying to imitate `twitter-api`. I've created a `json object` in my typescript and I'm trying to loop through my json in HTML. Here's my code:

**twitter-timeline.component.ts**

```
  output: JSON;
  twitter_data:any = {
      statuses: [
        {screen_name:"tanzeel", status: "wonderful day, enjoying at beach"},
        {screen_name:"pablo", status: "what a lovely morning #surfing #beach #relax"},
        {screen_name:"ricky", status: "feeling sick :-( #typhoid"}
      ]
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.output = <JSON>this.twitter_data;
  }
```

**twitter-timeline.component.html**

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let tweets of output; let i=index">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-column">
            <p class="screen-name">{{tweets.statuses[i].screen_name}}</p>
            <p class="user-status">{{tweets.statuses[i].status}}</p>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I'm creating JSON object, or there's something wrong with the way I'm reading values in HTML. Please correct me.

I also tried this kind of JSON structure:

```
output: JSON;
obj: any = 
{
"col1":{"Attribute1": "value1", "Attribute2": "value2", "Attribute3": "value3"},
"col2":{"Attribute1": "value4", "Attribute2": "value5", "Attribute3": "value6"}, 
"col3":{"Attribute1": "value7", "Attribute2": "value8", "Attribute3": "value9"} 
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `*ngFor` as `*ngFor="let tweets of output.statuses; let i=index"` .

`output` is an object so, you cannot iterate object like this, instead iterate the array `output.statuses` and then you can get the related data like,

```
        <p class="screen-name">{{tweets.screen_name}}</p>
        <p class="user-status">{{tweets.status}}</p>
```

You need to change `let tweets of output` **to** `let tweets of output.statuses`.

**twitter-timeline.component.html**

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let tweets of output.statuses; let i=index">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-column">
            <p class="screen-name">{{tweets.screen_name}}</p>
            <p class="user-status">{{tweets.status}}</p>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-few3gp)**

Comment: Oh. Now I understood. So the problem was the way I was reading the object and not the object itself. Thank you anna :-)

Comment: @Tanzeel, If you want to iterate the object, then you should check for angular doc on keyvalue pipe https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe .. And glad to help you again bro..